# SQL get number of unique client by browser

Tags: apache, logging, amazon-athena, presto, ansi-sql

I'm using AWS Athena to parse my Application Load Balancer logs.

I'm trying to get a list of browsers and for each browsers, the number of **unique** user.

I've managed to get this list but the user count is not correct. I don't know how to group users by their IP.

```
1   Google Chrome       9000000
2   Apple Safari        8000000
3   Unknown             5000000
4   Mozilla Firefox     2000000
5   Internet Explorer     10000
6   Outlook               10000
7   Opera                    88
8   Edge                      7
```

Here is the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE
    WHEN user_agent LIKE '%edge%'THEN 'Edge'
    WHEN user_agent LIKE '%MSIE%' THEN
    'Internet Explorer'
    WHEN user_agent LIKE '%Firefox%' THEN
    'Mozilla Firefox'
    WHEN user_agent LIKE '%Chrome%' THEN
    'Google Chrome'
    WHEN user_agent LIKE '%Safari%' THEN
    'Apple Safari'
    WHEN user_agent LIKE '%Opera%' THEN
    'Opera'
    WHEN user_agent LIKE '%Outlook%' THEN
    'Outlook'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS browser , COUNT(client_ip) AS Number
FROM alb_logs
WHERE parse_datetime(time,'yyyy-MM-DD''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS''Z')
    BETWEEN parse_datetime('2018-01-01-00:00:00','yyyy-MM-DD-HH:mm:ss')
        AND parse_datetime('2018-07-18-00:00:00','yyyy-MM-DD-HH:mm:ss')
GROUP BY  CASE
    WHEN user_agent LIKE '%edge%'THEN 'Edge'
    WHEN user_agent LIKE '%MSIE%' THEN
    'Internet Explorer'
    WHEN user_agent LIKE '%Firefox%' THEN
    'Mozilla Firefox'
    WHEN user_agent LIKE '%Chrome%' THEN
    'Google Chrome'
    WHEN user_agent LIKE '%Safari%' THEN
    'Apple Safari'
    WHEN user_agent LIKE '%Opera%' THEN
    'Opera'
    WHEN user_agent LIKE '%Outlook%' THEN
    'Outlook'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
    END
ORDER BY  Number DESC
```

I'm missing some kind of `group by client_ip`, but the result would be wrong...

Comment: Did you try  `COUNT(DISTINCT client_ip)` instead of `COUNT(client_ip)`?

Comment: No I didn't. Will it work if same IP but different browser? Will it count it as two separate users?

Comment: You group by browser, so same IP but different browsers will count separately (1 towards each browsers' count). BTW you should remove `DISTINCT` from `SELECT DISTINCT` and you can replace `GROUP BY CASE ... END` with just `GROUP BY 1`.

Comment: This should be an answer :-).
One last question: Can I have the average? Like having the number of all unique users

Comment: I will make it an answer then. I didn't get your last question though.

Comment: I want to have the % of users per browser. So I need the total amount of users.

Comment: I see now. Unfortunately, for this you would need to re-aggregate all the rows, something like:
`WITH your_query as ...
select *, Number / (select sum(Number) from your_query) from your_query`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `COUNT(DISTINCT client_ip)` aggregation and also you don't need `SELECT DISTINCT`, like this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN user_agent ... END AS browser, COUNT(DISTINCT client_ip) AS Number
FROM alb_logs
WHERE ...
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```